# Memory slowly increases, then stabilizes

Tags: c++, xcode, sdl-2

I currently have a rather small and simple C++ application using SDL2 on the most recent version of OS X. The only thing it's really doing is listening for a couple keyboard events and drawing a single, unfilled white square via a SDL_Renderer. It uses lambdas for things such as handling each frame's "tick" and rendering.

When I start running this program, XCode reports that it uses about 14.5MB of memory almost immediately. But then the memory usage slowly starts to increase, getting slower over time. Eventually, after a few minutes, it hits 18MB total, and pretty much stays there. Sometimes it will hit 18.1, but eventually it will drop back down to 18.

This behavior confuses me, because I'm not allocating anything in the my code except at the beginning. The only places where new memory is being used, is when I allocate an SDL_Rect on the stack in the render lambda, and a couple integers/floats in the main loop. This happens even when I don't cause any SDL_Events to be fired via keyboard, mouse, etc. If anyone can offer any suggestions as to why this might be happening, I would appreciate it.

Note that this doesn't seem to be a memory leak or anything dangerous, and is largely an academic question wherein I want to understand the behavior of what is going on. If you want me to put my code somewhere, I can.

Comment: Hi,  are you creating anything inside the render loop by any chance?

Comment: Just a stack-allocated SDL_Rect, with some numbers rounded into integers from a glm::vec2. That does use glm::round, and I don't know if glm::round allocates anything, but I assume not.